# How to access context.Database.SqlQuery in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx

but can't seem to to access this method, it will not show up in intelli-sense

```
context.Database.SqlQuery
```

I am using the following code but can't seem to access the SqlQuery method:

```
using(Entities db = new Entities())
{    
}
```

Comment: If you try to compile it, do you get any error message?

Comment: What version of EF are you using, ie is your context (`Entities`) a DbContext or an objectcontext

Comment: I am using ObjectContext

Answer (score 4):

The method you have described is valid for executing SQL vs a `DbContext` version of EF. (`DbContext` is used for Code First and is also available for model first but you need to do a little setup). However in your example it should be the following.

```
using(Entities db = new Entities())
{   
    db.Database.SqlQuery(....);
}
```

If you are using OOB model first (ie edmx), you are probably using an `ObjectContext`, in which case you will need to perform the following:

```
using(Entities db = new Entities())
{   
    db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ReturnType>("...");
}
```

See: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/11/25/execute-t-sql-statements-in-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: Does ExecuteStoreQuery allow the query to return an output value?

Comment: probably but im not too sure of the exact syntax. If your output value is a single int or string, putting that into the generic argument will probably give you the result you are after, although i havent tried this. Alternatly you could create a POCO class to match the response type and put that into the generic. There may also be a version returning object.

Answer (score 0):

```
return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
new object[] { param1, param2, param3 });
```

//Or

```
using(var context = new MyDataContext())
{
return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
new object[] { param1, param2, param3 }).ToList();
}
```

//Or

```
using(var context = new MyDataContext())
{
object[] parameters =  { param1, param2, param3 };

return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
parameters).ToList();
}
```

//Or

```
using(var context = new MyDataContext())
{  
return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
param1, param2, param3).ToList();
}
```

Comment: it is working for me for Assembly EntityFramework.dll, v4.4.0.0.
if you are using using(var context = new MyDataContext()) then .ToList() is mandatory.