# How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am very new to Entity Framework 6 and I want to implement stored procedures in my project. I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_department]
    @Name [varchar](100)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT [dbo].[Departments]([Name])
    VALUES (@Name)

    DECLARE @DeptId int

    SELECT @DeptId = [DeptId]
    FROM [dbo].[Departments]
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [DeptId] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT t0.[DeptId]
    FROM [dbo].[Departments] AS t0
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[DeptId] = @DeptId
END
```

`Department` class:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder 
.Entity<Department>() 
.MapToStoredProcedures(s => 
s.Update(u => u.HasName("modify_department") 
               .Parameter(b => b.Department, "department_id") 
               .Parameter(b => b.Name, "department_name")) 
 .Delete(d => d.HasName("delete_department") 
               .Parameter(b => b.DepartmentId, "department_id")) 
 .Insert(i => i.HasName("insert_department") 
               .Parameter(b => b.Name, "department_name")));

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string department = txtDepartment.text.trim();

    // here I want to call the stored procedure to insert values
}
```

**My problem is:** how can I call the stored procedure and pass parameters into it?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing that too. Ideally I'd skip EF altogether and run EVERYTHING through nothing but stored procedures. I'm an expert on SQL but have found EF very frustrating to implement.

Answer (score 281):

You can call a stored procedure in your `DbContext` class as follows.

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);
```

But if your stored procedure returns multiple result sets as your sample code, then you can see this helpful article on MSDN

[Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Alborz. can you please provide me some links regarding various implementation of Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 Code First. I searched everywhere on the web but didn't get any article where i can directly call a stored procedure for IN and OUT parameters. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: This article maybe helpful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx

Comment: Is that the same as creating `SQL command` and then execute it?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with parameters. It seems to need to explicitly list the parameters as part of the query.

Comment: Yes you do need to specify the params as part of the query - `"storedProcedureName @param1, @param2"`.  Also the type of `params` is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]`.

Comment: This answer is correct, but doesn't address that you CAN use stored procedure mapping to avoid using Database.SQLQuery().  See my answer or qujck's

Comment: `this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName @param1", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@param1", YourParam));`

Comment: I have included the usefull comments to improve this answer

Comment: Hi, I can't find dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<>, I have dbContext.TableName.SqlQuery.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez how is modifying the existing answer with an example (while useful) that has no context to the original question relevant? What are `FormularioVentasTO`, `sp_ConsultarSolicitud @idUsuario, @idSolicitud, codError` and `PortalFinandinaPriv`? Looks like you have just added cut/paste a piece of code that would be better as a separate answer and should also be in English which is one of the requires of [so]. Rolling Back.

Comment: @Lankymart so now code variable names have to be in english ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez well yeah, along with the example being relevant to the OPs code would be nice.

Comment: I have seen plenty of examples that dont use variables in english but whatever

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez it’s more the fact that the example wasn’t relevant to the OP question context.

Comment: YourContext.Database.SqlQuery<YourViewModel>("dbo.procname @p1, ...", value1,...)

Comment: What if your USP doesn't have any output?

Comment: The proposed answer didn't work. Indeed like the other comments, the parameters need to be added: exec sp_name paramname1, paramname2  Do not forget the comma's. so the C# code looks like this: this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("exec storedProcedureName paramname1, paramname2,",params);

Answer (score 171):

All you have to do is create an object that has the same property names as the results returned by the stored procedure. For the following stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetResultsForCampaign]  
    @ClientId int   
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT AgeGroup, Gender, Payout
    FROM IntegrationResult
    WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
    END
```

create a class that looks like:

```
    public class ResultForCampaign
    {
        public string AgeGroup { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public decimal Payout { get; set; }
    }
```

and then call the procedure by doing the following:

```
    using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
            var clientIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@ClientId", 4);

            var result = context.Database
                .SqlQuery<ResultForCampaign>("GetResultsForCampaign @ClientId", clientIdParameter)
                .ToList();
    }
```

The result will contain a list of `ResultForCampaign` objects. You can call `SqlQuery` using as many parameters as needed.

Comment: For one off situations, this would work great.  I find that the SProc definition should be tightly coupled with the class that inherits from DBContext, instead of out in the "wheat fields" of the product.

Answer (score 63):

I solved it with `ExecuteSqlCommand`

Put your own method like mine in DbContext as your own instances:

```
public void addmessage(<yourEntity> _msg)
{
    var date = new SqlParameter("@date", _msg.MDate);
    var subject = new SqlParameter("@subject", _msg.MSubject);
    var body = new SqlParameter("@body", _msg.MBody);
    var fid = new SqlParameter("@fid", _msg.FID);
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec messageinsert @Date , @Subject , @Body , @Fid", date,subject,body,fid);
}
```

so you can have a method in your code-behind like this:

```
[WebMethod] //this method is static and i use web method because i call this method from client side
public static void AddMessage(string Date, string Subject, string Body, string Follower, string Department)
{
    try
    {
        using (DBContext reposit = new DBContext())
        {
            msge <yourEntity> Newmsg = new msge();
            Newmsg.MDate = Date;
            Newmsg.MSubject = Subject.Trim();
            Newmsg.MBody = Body.Trim();
            Newmsg.FID= 5;
            reposit.addmessage(Newmsg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

this is my SP :

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.MessageInsert

    @Date nchar["size"],
    @Subject nchar["size"],
    @Body nchar["size"],
    @Fid int
AS
    insert into Msg (MDate,MSubject,MBody,FID) values (@Date,@Subject,@Body,@Fid)
    RETURN
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: You need to specify a length on the nchar parameters to your stored procedure - otherwise they are just one character long, as you've found.

Comment: This syntax requires no modification to the order of the SProc's Parameters, in other words Ordinal Positioning.

Comment: The ans i was looking for thanx

Comment: This is the correct answer from the book.

Answer (score 26):

Using your example, here are two ways to accomplish this:

**Approach #1**: use stored procedure mapping

Note that this code will work with or without mapping.  If you turn off mapping on the entity, EF will generate an insert + select statement.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (var db = DepartmentContext() )
     {
        var department = new Department();
        
        department.Name = txtDepartment.text.trim();
        
        db.Departments.add(department);
        db.SaveChanges();
        
        // EF will populate department.DepartmentId
        int departmentID = department.DepartmentId;
     }
}
```

**Approach #2**: call the stored procedure directly

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (var db = DepartmentContext() )
     {
        var name = new SqlParameter("@name", txtDepartment.text.trim());
        
        //to get this to work, you will need to change your select inside dbo.insert_department to include name in the resultset
        var department = db.Database.SqlQuery<Department>("dbo.insert_department @name", name).SingleOrDefault();

       //alternately, you can invoke SqlQuery on the DbSet itself:
       //var department = db.Departments.SqlQuery("dbo.insert_department @name", name).SingleOrDefault();
        
        int departmentID = department.DepartmentId;
     }
}
```

I recommend using the first approach, as you can work with the department object directly and not have to create a bunch of `SqlParameter` objects.

Comment: Be careful, is the second example the change is not tracked by the dbContext

Comment: EDIT.Use the System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>.SqlQuery(String, Object[]) instead.

Comment: @edtruant The dbContext does appear to track the change.  To test, I looked at db.<DbSet>.Count() before and after the insert statement.  In both methods, the count increased by one.   For completeness I added the alternate method to the example.

Comment: I don't see any reference to the stored procedure in the first example.

Comment: @xr280xr the insert_department is referenced in the modelBuilder expression in the OP's question.  That's the advantage to mapping things this way because it effectively functions the same way as if you were letting EF generate the insert/update/delete statements

Comment: @xr280xr There’s no reason to use EF if you’re going to call the stored procedure manually.

Answer (score 18):

You are using `MapToStoredProcedures()` which indicates that you are mapping your entities to stored procedures, when doing this you need to let go of the fact that there is a stored procedure and use the `context` as normal.
Something like this (*written into the browser so not tested*)

```
using(MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    Department department = new Department()
    {
        Name = txtDepartment.text.trim()
    };
    context.Set<Department>().Add(department);
}
```

If all you really trying to do is call a stored procedure directly then use [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks qujck. But i want to use stored procedure. I have given just a sample code for convenient to understand.

Comment: @Jaan - The code above *will* use the stored procedure. Do you mean you want to directly call the stored procedure?

Comment: yes. Can you please tell me which way is the better. Calling directly the stored procedure or the above code you have given?

Comment: @Jaan use the code I have shown - the ORM is meant to hide the underlying implementation - using the code above ensures that it doesn't matter to the rest of your code whether there's a stored procedure or not. You can even change the model mapping to another stored procedure or to not be a stored procedure without changing anything else.

Comment: Where are you calling a sproc in this answer?

Comment: @Chazt3n The question shows the stored procedures being configured from the line `.MapToStoredProcedures(s => `. A call to `Add` should resolve to `.Insert(i => i.HasName("insert_department")`

Comment: Trying to go from DataTables to using EF, thanks for the smack in the back of the head for this answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can now also use a convention I created which enables invoking stored procedures (including stored procedures returning multiple resultsets), TVFs and scalar UDFs natively from EF.

> Until Entity Framework 6.1 was released store functions (i.e. Table Valued Functions and Stored Procedures) could be used in EF only when doing Database First. There were some workarounds which made it possible to invoke store functions in Code First apps but you still could not use TVFs in Linq queries which was one of the biggest limitations. In EF 6.1 the mapping API was made public which (along with some additional tweaks) made it possible to use store functions in your Code First apps.

[Read more](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/)

> I pushed quite hard for the past two weeks and here it is – the beta version of the convention that enables using store functions (i.e. stored procedures, table valued functions etc.) in applications that use Code First approach and Entity Framework 6.1.1 (or newer). I am more than happy with the fixes and new features that are included in this release.

[Read more](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/08/11/the-beta-version-of-store-functions-for-entityframework-6-1-1-code-first-available/).

Comment: Actually since 4.0, you could execute SProcs without the Model.  You needed to execute Raw SQL statements instead of object property.  Even with 6.1.x, you have to use either SqlQuery<T> or ExecuteSqlCommand to obtain a similar effect.

Answer (score 14):

```
object[] xparams = {
            new SqlParameter("@ParameterWithNumvalue", DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@In_Parameter", "Value"),
            new SqlParameter("@Out_Parameter", SqlDbType.Int) {Direction = ParameterDirection.Output}};

YourDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec StoredProcedure_Name @ParameterWithNumvalue, @In_Parameter, @Out_Parameter", xparams);
var ReturnValue = ((SqlParameter)params[2]).Value;
```

Comment: params is an identifier use a different name.

Comment: The SaveChanges() here isn't necessary. Changes are committed at the ExecuteSqlCommand() call.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me by pulling back data from a stored procedure while passing in a parameter.

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@datetime", combinedTime);
var result = 
        _db.Database.SqlQuery<QAList>("dbo.GetQAListByDateTime @datetime", param).ToList();
```

*`_db` is the dbContext*

Answer (score 9):

Take a look to this link that shows how works the mapping of EF 6 with Stored Procedures to make an Insert, Update and Delete: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673

**Addition**

Here is a great example to call a stored procedure from Code First:

Lets say you have to execute an Stored Procedure with a single parameter, and that Stored Procedure returns a set of data that match with the Entity States, so we will have this:

```
var countryIso = "AR"; //Argentina

var statesFromArgentina = context.Countries.SqlQuery(
                                      "dbo.GetStatesFromCountry @p0", countryIso
                                                    );
```

Now lets say that we whant to execute another stored procedure with two parameters:

```
var countryIso = "AR"; //Argentina
var stateIso = "RN"; //Río Negro

var citiesFromRioNegro = context.States.SqlQuery(
                            "dbo.GetCitiesFromState @p0, @p1", countryIso, stateIso
                          );
```

Notice that we are using index-based naming for parameters. This is because Entity Framework will wrap these parameters up as DbParameter objects fro you to avoid any SQL injection issues.

Hope this example helps!

Answer (score 6):

```
public IList<Models.StandardRecipeDetail> GetRequisitionDetailBySearchCriteria(Guid subGroupItemId, Guid groupItemId)
{
    var query = this.UnitOfWork.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Models.StandardRecipeDetail>("SP_GetRequisitionDetailBySearchCriteria @SubGroupItemId,@GroupItemId",
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@SubGroupItemId", subGroupItemId),
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@GroupItemId", groupItemId));
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It work for me at code first. It return a list with matching property of view model(StudentChapterCompletionViewModel)

```
var studentIdParameter = new SqlParameter
{
     ParameterName = "studentId",
     Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt,
     Value = studentId
 };

 var results = Context.Database.SqlQuery<StudentChapterCompletionViewModel>(
                "exec dbo.sp_StudentComplettion @studentId",
                 studentIdParameter
                ).ToList();
```

**Updated for Context**

Context is the instance of the class that Inherit DbContext like below.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
}

var Context = new  ApplicationDbContext();
```

Comment: Hi, I can't find this Context.Database.SqlQuery<Model> , where as I can do this Context.TableName.SqlQuery(ProcName). which is giving me issues

Comment: @Marshall, maybe you are using the database first design. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792018/how-to-access-context-database-sqlquery-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 5):

I found that calling of stored procedures in code-first approach is not convenient.

I prefer to use `Dapper` instead.

The following code was written with Entity Framework:

```
var clientIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@ClientId", 4);

var result = context.Database
.SqlQuery<ResultForCampaign>("GetResultsForCampaign @ClientId", clientIdParameter)
.ToList();
```

The following code was written with `Dapper`:

```
return Database.Connection.Query<ResultForCampaign>(
            "GetResultsForCampaign ",
            new
            {
                ClientId = 4
            },
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I believe the second piece of code is simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters to `sp_GetById` and fetch the results either in `ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault();`

```
var param  = new SqlParameter("@id", 106);
var result = dbContext
               .Database
               .SqlQuery<Category>("dbo.sp_GetById @id", param)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mindless passenger](https://mindlesspassenger.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/code-first-and-stored-procedures/)  has a project that allows for multiple results sets to be returned from a stored proc using entity framework. One of his examples below....

```
using (testentities te = new testentities())
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Simple stored proc
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    var parms1 = new testone() { inparm = "abcd" };
    var results1 = te.CallStoredProc<testone>(te.testoneproc, parms1);
    var r1 = results1.ToList<TestOneResultSet>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core 5.0 does not have `FromSql` instead it has `FromSqlRaw`

All below worked for me. `Account` class here is Entity in C# with exact same table and column names as in the database.

App configuration class as below

```
class AppConfiguration
{
    public AppConfiguration()
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
        configBuilder.AddJsonFile(path, false);
        var root = configBuilder.Build();
        var appSetting = root.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
        sqlConnectionString = appSetting.Value;
    }

    public string sqlConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext class:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public class OptionsBuild
    {
        public OptionsBuild()
        {
            setting = new AppConfiguration();
            opsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>();
            opsBuilder.UseSqlServer(setting.sqlConnectionString);
            dbOptions = opsBuilder.Options;
        }

        public DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext> opsBuilder { get; set; }
        public DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> dbOptions { get; set; }

        private AppConfiguration setting { get; set; }
    }

    public static OptionsBuild ops = new OptionsBuild();

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        //disable initializer
        //  Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
}
```

This code should be in your data access layer:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
var context = new DatabaseContext(DatabaseContext.ops.dbOptions);
accounts = await context.Account.ToListAsync();   //direct select from a table

var param = new SqlParameter("@FirstName", "Bill");
accounts = await context.Account.FromSqlRaw<Account>("exec Proc_Account_Select", 
param).ToListAsync();            //procedure call with parameter
        
accounts = context.Account.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Account").ToList();  //raw query
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna pass table params into stored procedure, you must necessary set TypeName property for your table params.

```
SqlParameter codesParam = new SqlParameter(CODES_PARAM, SqlDbType.Structured);
            SqlParameter factoriesParam = new SqlParameter(FACTORIES_PARAM, SqlDbType.Structured);

            codesParam.Value = tbCodes;
            codesParam.TypeName = "[dbo].[MES_CodesType]";
            factoriesParam.Value = tbfactories;
            factoriesParam.TypeName = "[dbo].[MES_FactoriesType]";


            var list = _context.Database.SqlQuery<MESGoodsRemain>($"{SP_NAME} {CODES_PARAM}, {FACTORIES_PARAM}"
                , new SqlParameter[] {
                   codesParam,
                   factoriesParam
                }
                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what EF (DB first) generates in the DbContext class:

```
public ObjectResult<int> Insert_Department(string department)
{
    var departmentParameter = new ObjectParameter("department", department);

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<int>("insert_department", departmentParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When EDMX create this time if you select stored procedured in table select option then just call store procedured using procedured name...

```
var num1 = 1; 
var num2 = 2; 

var result = context.proc_name(num1,num2).tolist();// list or single you get here.. using same thing you can call insert,update or delete procedured.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ToSqlParamsString(this IDictionary<string, string> dict)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            foreach (var kvp in dict)
            {
                result += $"@{kvp.Key}='{kvp.Value}',";
            }
            return result.Trim(',', ' ');
        }

public static List<T> RunSproc<T>(string sprocName, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            string command = $"exec {sprocName} {parameters.ToSqlParamsString()}";
            return Context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(command).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing have to do... when you are creating dbcontext for code first approach initialize
namespace below the fluent API area make list of sp and use it another place where you want.

```
public partial class JobScheduleSmsEntities : DbContext
{
    public JobScheduleSmsEntities()
        : base("name=JobScheduleSmsEntities")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<JobScheduleSmsEntities>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<JobScheduleSmsEntities>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ReachargeDetail> ReachargeDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RoleMaster> RoleMasters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Types().Configure(t => t.MapToStoredProcedures());

        //modelBuilder.Entity<RoleMaster>()
        //     .HasMany(e => e.Customers)
        //     .WithRequired(e => e.RoleMaster)
        //     .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleID)
        //     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
    public virtual List<Sp_CustomerDetails02> Sp_CustomerDetails()
    {
        //return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Sp_CustomerDetails02>("Sp_CustomerDetails");
        //  this.Database.SqlQuery<Sp_CustomerDetails02>("Sp_CustomerDetails");
        using (JobScheduleSmsEntities db = new JobScheduleSmsEntities())
        {
           return db.Database.SqlQuery<Sp_CustomerDetails02>("Sp_CustomerDetails").ToList();

        }

    }

}
```

}

```
public partial class Sp_CustomerDetails02
{
    public long? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public long? CustID { get; set; }
    public long? Customer_ID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? CountDay { get; set; }
    public int? EndDateCountDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RenewDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSMS { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MySql and Entity framework code first Approach:

```
public class Vw_EMIcount
{
    public int EmiCount { get; set; }
    public string Satus { get; set; }
}

var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Vw_EMIcount>("call EMIStatus('2018-3-01' ,'2019-05-30')").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create Procedure in MYsql.**

```
delimiter //
create procedure SP_Dasboarddata(fromdate date, todate date)
begin
select count(Id) as count,date,status,sum(amount) as amount from 
details
where (Emidate between fromdate and todate)
group by date ,status;
END;
//
```

**Create class which contains stored procedure return result set values**

```
[Table("SP_reslutclass")]
public  class SP_reslutclass
{
    [Key]
    public int emicount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Emidate { get; set; }
    public int ? Emistatus { get; set; }
    public int emiamount { get; set; }

}
```

**Add Class in Dbcontext**

```
  public  class ABCDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ABCDbContext(DbContextOptions<ABCDbContext> options)
       : base(options)
    {

    }

 public DbSet<SP_reslutclass> SP_reslutclass { get; set; }
}
```

**Call entity in repository**

```
   var counts = _Dbcontext.SP_reslutclass.FromSql("call SP_Dasboarddata 
                    ('2019-12-03','2019-12-31')").ToList();
```