# How to make use of an existing stored procedures in entity framework 6 using mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6.1

How can I map a custom stored procedure in entity framework 6 code first approach?
Not with using predefined Insert, Update and Delete methods of entity framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: sorry but without using the MapToStoredProcedure(s=>s.Insert(),Update(),Delete()); cant it be mapped to the procedures.