# Execute stored procedure using Entity Framework using LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am getting

> Incorrect syntax near 'ABC.Security.GetUserLocation'.

when executing a stored procedure with the following code.

`.` dots are the part of Name (for grouping), don't confuse it with Schema.

Something like "FirstName.LastName". I can execute it from SSMS without any problem.

```
var userNameToSearch = new SqlParameter("@userName", userName);
userNameToSearch.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
userNameToSearch.Size = 100;

List<Location> locations = db.Database.SqlQuery<Location>(@"[ABC.Security.GetUserLocation]", userNameToSearch).ToList();

return locations;
```

What would be the right way to use names like that from C# code ?

Comment: Try `"EXEC [ABC.Security.GetUserLocation] {0}"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to be explicit with your parameters

```
List<Location> locations = db.Database.SqlQuery<Location>(@"exec [ABC.Security.GetUserLocation] {0}", userNameToSearch).ToList();
```

"{0}" means that you are passing **userNameToSearch** as first parameter, doesnt matter whats the parameter's name.

Comment: The first parameter need to be string value(or literal value) and not an SQLParameter at for SQL 2005 Version.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a stored procedure in your DbContext class as follows.

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);
```

here more information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

this was an answer from this question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)