# How to Create Custom Stored Procedures Using Code First Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, ef-fluent-api

There are many articles that show how to create Insert, Update, Delete procedures using Code First like this [one](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx).

How about custom procedure like this simple select statement:

```
Select * from Customers
```

I could make changes to the Up and Down Migration methods, but is there a way to create custom procs using Fluent API **directly**.

Comment: for more info about DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which I don't recommand but If you want to use `DbContext.Database`, here it is:

```
using(var db = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure ... END;");

    var command = "EXEC MyProcedure;";
    IEnumerable<Customer> customers = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(command, null);
}
```

Comment: excellent but in this case, how calling this procedure will map to a model that does not even exist? I mean the ExecuteSqlCommand creates the proc in db but then the proc result will have no class representation in the Model.

Comment: use `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>` to map procedure result into your model. I have updated my answer

Comment: In Database First, EntityFramework used to create a model that represent the proc result for example: GetCustomers_Result. Or do I have to create this manually?

Comment: @usefulBee since you can still use `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)` to seed database, It would be hard to maintain or handle migrations for stored procedure code in this way.

Comment: I found the following techinque to be helpfull as well for calling the stored proc without passing a string: var result = db.Set<Customer>().ToList(); as found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20905566/2093880