# How to convert this SQL to LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query in SQL query as like below:

```
with pagedetail as
(
    select  
        c.componentrefid, l.name, c.startdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION By c.componentrefid order by c.startdate desc) as rownumber 
    from 
        FM_componentTransaction as c 
    inner join 
        FM_LK_statusinfo as l on c.Statusinforefid = l.refid
    inner join 
        fm_scriptinfo as s on s.Refid = c.ScriptRefId
    where 
        s.CustomerInfoRefId = '85629125-7072-4EFE-9201-97E088E126C6'
)
select 
    pd.* 
from 
    pagedetail pd 
where 
    pd.rownumber = 1
```

I can get the output of this. Now my questions is how to implement this query using Entity Framework?

Comment: where is your query?

Comment: I edited now. Please check it

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, however one approach would be to create a stored procedure in SQL, and then just call the stored procedure in Entity Framework.

Code first:
[How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Database First:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Comment: yes zapnologica. i m doing this by stored procedure

Comment: Then all you need to do, is create a Database first model of your database. And then when you instantiate a new instance of your `Db Context`  you can go `dbContext.StoredprocedureName`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following model:

```
public class ComponentTransaction
{
    public Guid componentrefid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime startdate { get; set; }
    public Guid Statusinforefid { get; set; }
    public Guid ScriptRefId { get; set; }
}

public class Statusinfo
{
    public Guid refid { get; set; }
}

public class Scriptinfo
{
    public Guid refid { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerInfoRefId { get; set; }
}
```

The code can look like this:

```
Db db = new Db();
Guid customerInfoRefId = new Guid("85629125-7072-4EFE-9201-97E088E126C6");
var res = db.ComponentTransactions
    .GroupBy(c => c.componentrefid)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.startdate).First())
    .Join(db.Statusinfos, c => c.Statusinforefid, l => l.refid, (c, l) => c)
    .Join(db.Scriptinfos.Where(s => s.CustomerInfoRefId == customerInfoRefId), 
        c => c.ScriptRefId, s => s.refid, (c, s) => c);
```

Comment: Thank you ivan. let me try this soltuion