# MVC 5, EF 6, and "Code First from Database" Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

In searching for an answer, even with the keywords "Code First from Database" in quotes, I found that the answers did not address the specific terms, so I'm asking the question with a specific emphasis on "Code First from Database" only.

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application using Entity Framework 6, I would like to be able to use the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" wizard to map to an existing stored procedure on a database.

*Why am I asking the question and what do I hope to accomplish?*

This particular stored procedure is a parameterized query, where the user (in the View) would submit by form a date range and receive the results of that query in the table. On the SQL Server side, it is easy: declare two dates and get your query results.

I would like the user, from the View, to "simply" select a date range and see the results immediately below as supplied by the stored procedure query.

Below are screenshots showing my attempt to use the wizard to map the stored procedure.

**1. Specify name of database context**

[image: Specify name of database context]

**2. Specify "Code First From Database"**

[image: Specify "Code First From Database"]

**3. Choose Database Connection**

[image: Choose Database Connection]

**4. No stored procedures are available**

I also notice that the option to import stored procedures is greyed out.

[image: No stored procedures are available]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:  Tarun mentioned the stored procedures aren't showing up due to lack of permissions.

Entity Framework provide APIs to call stored procedures though, you can even map a stored procedure to a model.

See this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx

To bind a model to a stored procedure:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().MapToStoredProcedures();
```

If you are not interested in mapping a stored procedure see this post:

[How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: I'm trying this approach, but I am getting this error "No mapping exists from object type System.DateTime[] to a known managed provider native type." `DateTime[] parameters = new DateTime[2] { d1, d2 };
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<PerfOdomoeterDate>("GetCreditSumByDateRange",parameters).ToList();` Still working on it.

Comment: I'm marking yours as the answer. There were some learning curve errors I made, but it was the "How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?" that ended up being most beneficial. I'll add a full step-by-step procedure in my own answer shortly.

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to my question is that there is no way I can trick the wizard to import a stored procedure.

Instead, this is what I needed to do:

1. Make sure that my stored procedure had an ID column of type int

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT ID = cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>               ORDER BY z.Campus,
>                   z.StudentName,
>                   z.StudentID
>               ) AS INT),
>       -- ....
> ```

2. In the Models folder, manually create my class and property definition.

> ```
> public class PerfOdomoeterDate
> {        
>   public int ID { get; set; }
>   public string Campus { get; set; }
>   public string StudentName { get; set; }
>   public int StudentID { get; set; }
>   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
>   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
>   public double Credits { get; set; }
> }
> ```

3. In the database context file, add:

> `public virtual DbSet<PerfOdomoeterDate> PerfOdomoeterDates { get; set; }`

4. Do not add anything to the "OnModelCreating" function.
5. Right-click the Controllers folder and a new scaffolded Item: "MVC 5 Controller with Entity Framework".
6. The Index action shown is a "hello world" sample to make sure that basic contact is made with the Stored Procedure. I will definitely customize it with a View  Model, parameters, etc. But this should clearly show how to get your code to work.

> ```
> private PerformanceContext db = new PerformanceContext();        
>
> [HttpGet]
> public ActionResult Index()
> {   
>   // These will be filled by form submission
>   DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime("12/1/2014");
>   DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime("5/1/2015");
>
>   // supply parameter values required by the stored procedure
>   object[] parameters = {
>       new SqlParameter("@date1",SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value=d1},
>       new SqlParameter("@date2",SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value=d2}
>                    };
>
>   // populate the list by calling the stored procedure and supplying parameters
>   IEnumerable<PerfOdomoeterDate> query = 
>       db.Database.SqlQuery<PerfOdomoeterDate>("PerfOdomoeterDate @date1, @date2", 
>           parameters).ToList();            
>
>   return View(query);
> }
> ```

7. Rebuild and view the Index. There should be no compile or runtime errors. The View should show the required data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings!

Answer (score 2):

Permissions.(Make sure the db user has the permissions on the stored procedure

Comment: I had already verified permissions and reconfirmed them. For me, this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can do this from the Wizard as of yet, generating from stored procs is a relatively new feature.

To map to procs from the code you will need to do the following

```
modelBuilder 
  .Entity<Blog>() 
  .MapToStoredProcedures();
```

The full details are in this post

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx

Comment: In a recent project,I did import some stored procedures using the same wizard,Its a problem with permissions I guess

Comment: @TarunPothulapati - are you sure u didn't use the Database First wizard? I can do the import of stored procs via Database First but not Code First and I believe it's just not supported yet.