# Display value on textbox on change of the date

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Good Day! I am a newbie on ASP.NET (MVC) and trying to display a value (from a Stored Procedure) after the value of the date has been changed. This is what it looks like on the design [Once the date is picked, the user will click the Create button and the value should be displayed on the "Sales" textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o743t.png)

This is my Stored Procedure for it

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_DAILY_SALES] 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Order_date date
 
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
BEGIN TRY
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;



 DECLARE @SumTable table
 (
  dailySales decimal (18,2) 
 )


 DECLARE @dailySales decimal(18,2)
 SET @dailySales = (
     SELECT SUM(NET_AMOUNT)
     FROM [ORDER]
     WHERE ORDER_DATE=@Order_date)

INSERT INTO @SumTable (dailySales)
  VALUES (@dailySales)



    -- Insert statements for procedure here
  SELECT dailySales
  FROM @SumTable




 COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
```

and this is where I call it (Repository)

```html
   public bool DisplayDailySales(DateTime orderdate)
        {

            connection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_DAILY_SALES", con);

            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.Add("@Order_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = orderdate;
            con.Open();
            int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }


        }
```

My Controller

```html
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Statistics()
        {

            OrderVM dSales = new OrderVM();
            var currentdate = DateTime.Now;
            dSales.ORDER_DATE = currentdate;

            return View();


        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Statistics(OrderVM order)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime orderdate = order.ORDER_DATE;
                ViewData["ORDERDATE"] = orderdate;



                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    OrderRepository orderRepo = new OrderRepository();
                    orderRepo.DisplayDailySales(orderdate);



                }
                return View();

            }
            catch
            {

                return View();
            }




        }
```

And lastly, in my view as of now is this

```html
                <div class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDER_DATE, "Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4" })
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ORDER_DATE, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @id = "Orderdate" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDER_DATE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dailySales, "Sales", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4" })
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dailySales, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dailySales, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3 pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

           
                    }
           
        </div>
```

Hope someone can help me out on this. Thank You!

Comment: So where's your question?

Comment: @JamesZ Oh, I'm sorry. I was just wondering what's missing (or wrong) with my codes because when the Create button is clicked, it does not display anything.

Comment: If you don't know about use SP in EntityFramework look at this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: you can do exec [dbo].[SP_DAILY_SALES]  ' date you are selecting ' and check if query returns data

Comment: Hi there @coder771 ! The SP does return correct data.

Comment: is it returning anything at all?

Comment: Hi @coder771 when I execute my SP on the Sql server, it returns the correct data. It just doesn't execute properly on my code. I think I'm missing something I just couldn't quite pin point it.

Comment: are you filling model with the sales when returning view on controller. i dont think so.