# How to call stored procedures in Entity Framework properly without modifying auto-generate context.cs file?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

In my project I use Entity Framework as my data access layer. I create a stored procedure `InitPartitionStorePos` and imported it. When I call the corresponding function like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> InitPartitionStorePos(Nullable<int> maxPos, string machineCode)
{
   var maxPosParameter = maxPos.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("maxPos", maxPos) :
        new ObjectParameter("maxPos", typeof(int));

    var machineCodeParameter = machineCode != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("machineCode", machineCode) :
        new ObjectParameter("machineCode", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("InitPartitionStorePos", maxPosParameter, machineCodeParameter);
}
```

It throws an exception:

> The FunctionImport 'InitPartitionStorePos' could not be found in the container 'PartitionEntities'

Using the code below prints nothing

```
ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

MetadataWorkspace space = ctx.MetadataWorkspace;
EntityContainer ct;

space.TryGetEntityContainer(ctx.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace, out ct);    

foreach(EdmFunction candidate in ct.FunctionImports)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(candidate.Name);
}
```

The edmx file:

[image]

I want to know why the EF6 could not find the import function?

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015. The Entity Framework version is 6.1.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: check this, it's much easier... :)

Comment: Try deleting the edmx and re-creating it

Comment: @Dumisani I have tried, but not work.