# How do I call a database 'select' stored procedure with parameters, from a MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-controller

I currently have a controller which populates a partial view with all rows from a database view.

```
public ActionResult SearchResults()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/TransactionHistory/_SearchResults.cshtml", db.TRANSACTION_HISTORY.ToList());
}
```

`TRANSACTION_HISTORY` is the name of the model class. and also the database view from which I am displaying the rows. `db` is my database context object.

This is my model class:

```
namespace TransactionHistory.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TRANSACTION_HISTORY
    {
        public int INTERFACE_RECORD_ID { get; set; }
        public string COMPANY { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Carrier { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Connote { get; set; }
        public string Order_Type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Volume { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Weight { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Post_Code { get; set; }
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public string Book_In { get; set; }
        public string Deliver_From { get; set; }
        public string Deliver_To { get; set; }
        public string Trpt_Special_Instructions { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Created { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> From_Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> To_Date { get; set; }
        public string Picklist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, I have a stored procedure which operates on this view, named `TRANSACTION_HISTORY_SEARCH`. Now this accepts 2 parameters (`FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE`) in it's where clause, and returns the exact same number of rows as the view (which means I do not want to use a different model for storing the rows returned by the stored procedure).

So how do I make use of the controller's `ActionResult` method to actually get the results returned by the stored procedure, rather than all rows returned by the database view?

I do understand that I need to use `[HttpPost]` for this action, since I'll be passing those parameters for the stored procedure from my view (textbox entries).

Comment: (1) You do not need a POST (it can be a GET since your not changing data). (2) Why not a simple a linq `.Where()` clause  e.g. `db.TRANSACTION_HISTORY.Where(x => FROM_DATE >= fromDate && x => x.TO_DATE <= toDate);`?

Comment: Thank you.

It's just that I am working on legacy databases, which already have stored procedures and my employers prefer that I use them. I have a meeting later on to try and convince them to allow me to use LINQ instead.

So do I just pass this LINQ query as a parameter to the 'return PartialView' function?

Comment: Yes, (where `fromDate` and `toDate` are parameters in your method (the values of the textboxes). But the fact that your returning `PartialView` also suggest your using ajax. But if you want to do this using a SP, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first) for an example

Comment: I tried your LINQ expression, but there is an error for FROM_DATE and TO_DATE, which says these names do not exist in the current context. Do I have to pass the model as a parameer to my SearchResults() function? Looks to be that way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you model/table fields are (you have not shown them!) Just replace then with the actual property names

Comment: @StephenMuecke

Yes, the names are the same (I have also used the same case). I just updated my question with the code of my model. The model was generated directly from a database view which already existed.

Comment: Got it resolved by reformatting the LINQ query in a different way. But my employers insist on using stored procedures, so I am digging into the link your provided. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database) property and call the stored procedure using [SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601(System.String,System.Object[])). 
Something like this:

```
 List<TRANSACTION_HISTORY> res;

 res = db.TRANSACTION_HISTORY
         .Database
         .SqlQuery<TRANSACTION_HISTORY>("TRANSACTION_HISTORY_SEARCH @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE",
                                        new SqlParameter("@FROM_DATE", fromDate),
                                        new SqlParameter("@TO_DATE",   toDate))
         .ToList();
```