# Call stored procedure using Entity Framework which returns single string with no column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a single date string based on some logic with no column name.

[image: SQL Output window]

My C# code using entiry framework

```
public string GetCurrTimeForUser(string userId)
    {

        using (var context = new RMTest())
        {
            var user_id = new SqlParameter("@USER_ID", userId);

            var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC PROC_GET_UTC_DATE",user_id);
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and the output I am getting is "EXEC PROC_GET_UTC_DATE";

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: your stored procedure does not have column name from the select statement

Comment: No , unfortunately I can not change the stored procedure.

Comment: and why would you need a column for? since it's only returning one column result/

Comment: I just want to get same result using c# code. Which I am unable to get.

Comment: I don't know the content of this RMTest, but try to remove <string>. make sure you are using commandText Stored procedure

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first ?  Remove `EXEC  ` from your statement.

Answer (score -1):

When calling a stored procedure:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery("EXEC PROC_GET_UTC_DATE '" + user_id + "'")
```

It's almost like that

Comment: Hope this one RMTest()  is okay

Comment: And SQL Injection?

Comment: You ***SHOULD REALLY*** use a **parametrized query** approach rather than concatenating together your SQL statement - this just **asks** for SQL injection to happen! **DON'T DO THIS** - ever!