# How to create DbSet for ignored entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to create DbSet for my ignored entity.
Now I have in my modelBuilder next code:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<ExtendedDepartment>();
```

And inside my DbSet I have:

```
public DbSet<ExtendedDepartment> ExtendedDepartments { get; set; }
```

When I`m trying to get data from that Dbset I have error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for ExtendedDepartment because this type is not included in the model for the context.
```

So I am trying to ignore this table in migration, maybe I am doing smthing wrong.

Comment: Why did you need to ignore the table in migration? For generating `ExtendedDepartments` table and access `DbSet<ExtendedDepartments >`, you should not use `modelBuilder.Ignore<ExtendedDepartment>();`. If you real want to ignore the migration, you need to modify the generated `migration.cs` file to remove the code related with `ExtendedDepartment`. In general, there is no need to because if you did not change anyting in `ExtendedDepartment`, it would not generate migration for `ExtendedDepartment` table. If you changed, you should keep the table udpate.

Comment: This table should be empty. So I dont need it in my db.  I wonna use it just to get some data from two tables. So Im using SP for that and I cant do method from EF Include(). I`m trying to find alternative for that.

Comment: What is "SP'? If the data for `ExtendedDepartment` is from two tables, there is no need to define `DbSet<ExtendedDepartment>`in the DbContext, you could query ExtendedDepartment from the two tables.

Comment: Stored Procedures)

Comment: Mapping SP to DbSet is not supported currently. Currently, you only could run SP from `DbSet` by `FromSql`. You may consider use  [Entity Framework Core - Mapping Stored Procedures, Fluently](https://www.sinclairinat0r.com/2017/05/06/entity-framework-core--mapping-stored-procedures,-fluently) to extend DbContext instead of using `DbSet<T>`.

Comment: May be you need [Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types)?