# Query stored proc with parameters in Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So far I was calling my stored procedures like :

```
using (Entities ent = new Entities())
{
    test = atlEnt.Database.SqlQuery<GetCarriersById_Result>("CarriersById @CarID, @FacilityID",
    new SqlParameter("@CarID", id)
    , new SqlParameter("@FacilityID", facilityId)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

How can I add the parameters with a separate statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *with a separate statements*, why do you care if it's separate statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify parameters as to have this in separate line

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CarID", id));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FacilityID", facilityId));
```

And invoke the query as

```
test = atlEnt.Database.SqlQuery<GetCarriersById_Result>("CarriersById @CarID, @FacilityID", parameters.ToArray());
```

You can check the documentation of `SqlQuery` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%28System.Type,System.String,System.Object[]%29). The `SqlQuery` method allows to specify parameters as params.