# Where to find stored procedure in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have added stored procedures along with some table through entity framework
i can able to see tables under xyzContext.tt but no SP's are visible there
and how can check my SP is loaded into a project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to the edmx model in the solution explorer and then double click on it to open it. Once the model is open, right click to bring up the context menu and select the 'Model Browser' option.

[image: Context Menu]

Once the model browser is open you should be able to find the stored procedures contained in the model under the stored procedures folder:

[image: EMDX Model Browser]

If the stored procedures that you added do not appear here then check the visual studio 'Error List' window as there may be something wrong with them and the errors should be reported here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first, then you can add SP to DbContext using method [MapToStoredProcedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.manytomanynavigationpropertyconfiguration-2.maptostoredprocedures?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
                    .MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
```