# Linq - Merging two statements that use the same method

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am trying to rewrite and integrate the following code in to a single statement:

So instead of having to do this:

```
     var dbList = await _context.ProfileSections.Select(p => new
        {
            p.Id,
            p.Description,
            p.InformationText
        }).ToListAsync();

        var localisedList = dbList.Select(p => new
        {
            p.Id,
            Description = p.Description.Translate(),
            Information = p.InformationText.Translate()
        }).ToList();
```

I assume I could use if I strongly type to a model and use a foreach, something like:

```
 var dbList = await _context.ProfileSections.Select(p => new ProfileSectionModel
        {
            p.Id,
            p.Description,
            p.InformationText
        }).ToListAsync();

        var localisedList = dbList.ForEach(l => {
            l.Description = l.Description.Translate();
            l.InformationText = l.InformationText.Translate();
        }).ToList();
```

However then get error message: `Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'`

So is there an easier to combine the two statements? Or will I always have to as the first returns an anonymouse type. Unsure what is the correct way to handle this?

**EDIT**

Could use the following but was then getting issue with the dynamic proxies that EF uses. I guess thats why its selecting into an anonymous type?

```
    var dbList = await _context.ProfileSections.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var item in dbList)
    {
        item.Description = item.Description.Translate(),
        item.Information = item.InformationText.Translate()
    }
```

Comment: see new code in new answer

Comment: "I am trying to rewrite and integrate the following code in to a single statement:" - I suppose conciseness has a place, but *why* exactly are you after a single statement here? These two statements do fundamentally different things - one *goes to a database* and the other simply does some mapping. Just because they have sort-of-the-same-shape doesn't mean they *have* to be stuck together. (btw, your title refers to "2 foreach statements" but I don't see any here...)

Comment: `dbList` is of type `List`. `List.ForEach` isn't a function but a procedure - it returns no value, its purpose is to execute side-effects in the lambda. So you are modifying `dbList` in the `ForEach` just like you had a regular `foreach` loop - which would be a better way to go. `List.ForEach` is rarely a good idea. So `.ToList()` and `var x = ` makes no sense with `ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont't use ForEach at all. You can do it in one go within the LINQ Select Statement. As for your error: I suppose it comes from `dbList.ForEach` which is not correct usage.

```
void Main()
{
    var listOne = new List<dings>{
        new dings() {id = 1, name = "aaa"},
        new dings() {id = 2, name = "bbb"},
        new dings() {id = 3, name = "ccc"},
    };

    var listTwo = listOne.Select(x => new bums() 
        {
            idbums = x.id + 33, 
            namebums = x.name + "hoho"
        }
    ).ToList();
}

public class dings{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

public class bums
{
    public int idbums;
    public string namebums;
}
```

Comment: Then get error if I use Translate() method directly in `dbList` -- NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method &#x27;System.String Translate(System.String)&#x27; method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 0):

Use a Join like this :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataBase _context = new DataBase();

            List<ProfileSections> localisedList = new List<ProfileSections>();

            var results = localisedList  
                           .Select(p => new
                           {
                               Id = p.Id,
                               Description = p.Description,
                               InformationText = p.InformationText,
                               TranslateDescription = p.TranslateDescription,
                               TranslateInformationText = p.TranslateInformationText
                           }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<ProfileSections> ProfileSections { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProfileSections
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string InformationText { get; set; }

        public string TranslateInformationText
        {
            get { return TranslateFunction(InformationText); }
            set { ;}
        }

        public string TranslateDescription
        {
            get { return TranslateFunction(Description); }
            set { ;}
        }

        private string TranslateFunction(string s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apologise if unclear in example - `.Translate()` is method that is translating the Value for `Description` & `InformationText` thats held in Database. I basically just want to run this method on the results from `dbList`

Comment: I updated code but not sure if localisedList is the same type as the dbContext.  You may want to look at this posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first

Answer (score 0):

Since your translate method does not work within the LINQ query, a `foreach` might indeed be useful. Try like that:

```
void Main()
{
    var listOne = new List<dings>{
        new dings() {id = 1, name = "aaa"},
        new dings() {id = 2, name = "bbb"},
        new dings() {id = 3, name = "ccc"},
    };

    var listTwo = new List<bums>();
    foreach (var item in listOne)
    {
        listTwo.Add(
        new bums()
            {
                idbums = item.id + 33,
                namebums = item.name + "hoho"
            }
        );
    }
}

public class dings
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

public class bums
{
    public int idbums;
    public string namebums;
}
```