# Call stored procedure does not belong to context

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

I want to call a stored procedure that does not belong to my `.EDMX`, but the procedure exists in the database.

Could I call it from my code even if the procedure is not in my `.EDMX`?

If it's possible could you provide me with some sample code?

Thanks!

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: which of these did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first

Comment: Oracle database

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the stored procedure directly like this: call stored procedure `GetEmployeById` with parameter `@Id`

```
using (var ctx = new DBEntities())
{
    var idParam = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "Id",Value = 1};

    //Get employee by id
    var employeeList = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Employee>("exec GetEmployeById @Id ", idParam).ToList<Employee>();

    foreach (employee emp in employeeList)
       Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: {0}",emp.Name);
  }
```

For more documentation check this [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx)