# Using stored procedure to produce excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use this stored procedure below to create a list which I can then export as an Excel file. I have been using Entity Framework thus far, but I am unsure how to go about this in my controller:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFlugReport]     
(      
   @AccNo INTEGER,
   @DateFrom DATE, 
   @DateTo DATE    
)      
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[KIRData] 
    WHERE AccNo = @AccNo 
      AND StartDate >= @DateFrom 
      AND EndDate <= @DateTo 
      AND Prod = 'Air'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a combination of 2 questions:

1. How to call a stored procedure, and
2. How to create an Excel document

For calling a stored procedure, there is a good thread here that should be useful to you, it explains how to use Entity to call a stored procedure
[How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first?rq=1)

Second, to create an Excel document I'd suggest you have a look at ClosedXML, it's pretty straight forward to use and has proven reliable at producing Excel docs https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml and https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML

Hope that helps.