# Getting table size using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF6 and I am trying to get the table sizes. I believe this should work but the result comes back as zero:

```
public class SqlRes{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

var size = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SqlRes>("exec sp_spaceused Customer").ToList();
```

I have also tried to use type like string or int with no success. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property names of `SqlRes` should match the column names returned by the stored procedure.

According to [SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the column names are:

- name
- rows
- reserved
- data
- index_size
- unused

Try changing your `SqlRes` class to have those property names.

Comment: but that's not all. "exec" is not required and Customer should be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Removed the exec and changed the SqlRes's property to 'data', and now it works.