# Database update fails when using edit

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This exception occurs when I try to edit my database using stored procedure with Entity Framework:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.'

This is my code:

```cs
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }

                reg reg = db.regs.Find(id);

                if (reg == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                return View(reg);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(reg regs)
    {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Traning_ASPEntities1 dbcontext = new Traning_ASPEntities1();
                    dbcontext.Entry(regs).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    dbcontext.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("display");
                }

                return View(regs);
    }
```

reg model class:

```cs
    namespace UserReg.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

        public partial class reg
        {
            public int userid { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="First Name")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter your first name")]
            [MaxLength(25,ErrorMessage ="should not exceed 25 characters")]
            public string fname { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Last Name")]
            [MaxLength(30,ErrorMessage ="Should not exceed 30 characters")]
            public string lname { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Age")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your age")]
            [Range(18,70,ErrorMessage ="Age must be between 18 & 70")]
            public Nullable<int> age { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Gender")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="please specify your gender")]
            public string gender { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Email")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="Enter your email")]
            [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Enter a valid email id")]
            public string email { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Phone")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Phone number")]
            [RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$", ErrorMessage ="enter a valid phone number")]
            public string phone { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Username")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your username")]
            [MaxLength(25,ErrorMessage ="should not exceed 25 characters")]
            public string uname { get; set; }

            [Display(Name ="Password")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter your password")]
            [MaxLength(15,ErrorMessage ="Must not exceed 15 characters")]
            [MinLength(4,ErrorMessage ="must contain atleast 4 characters")]
            [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{4,}$",ErrorMessage = "Minimum 4 characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string pswd { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "please re-enter your password")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Compare("pswd",ErrorMessage ="Passwords do not match")]
            public string cpswd { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Stored procedure to update:

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[regup] 
        @userid INT,
        @fname VARCHAR(50),
        @lname VARCHAR(50),
        @age INT,
        @gender VARCHAR(1),
        @email VARCHAR(MAX),
        @phone VARCHAR(15)
    AS
    BEGIN
        --update reg set lname='asdf' where reg.userid=@userid
        UPDATE reg 
        SET fname = @fname, 
            lname = @lname,
            age = @age,
            gender = @gender,
            email = @email,
            phone = @phone 
        WHERE userid = @userid
    END
```

Comment: please show the reg  model

Comment: here is reg model

Comment: userid  has value?

Comment: yes,userid has value

Comment: Where are you calling the stored procedure? the only thing I see is `dbcontext.Entry(regs).State = EntityState.Modified;` which will not work currently

Comment: you do not use stored procedure now. you use the entityframework update. for using the stored procedure check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20911004/7086678)

Comment: Stored procedure is mapped to the entity model

Comment: Only the edit view is showing this problem. insert delete works perfectly with the stored procedure

Comment: You do not call any stored procedure (or if you are, you don't show the code where you do that), the problem is in your model, where EF is unable to determine the correct ordering of its statements. Also, please do remember to dispose of your contexts once they are no longer needed.