# Is a DbSet required to run a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-core-3.0

I have a stored procedure that returns data from a multi-table query.  To do this do I need to create a DbSet for each of the tables that are involved in the query?  All the examples I find that use FromSql have a DbSet (e.g., Books in the below example) specified before the FromSql clause.

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var books = context.Books
        .FromSql("EXEC GetAllBooks")
        .ToList();
}
```

My understanding is a DbSet represents an table.  Note that I am working against an existing DB so am not using EF to generate the tables.

Thanks,

Comment: We're executing our SP's with ADO.NET and copy the result data by ourself into our domain objects. Works fast enough for us.

Comment: You can do the above but you wont be able to return an object graph in a single stored proc call. Also you do not need a DbSet, you could also use `context.Database.SqlQuery` but you *should* still provide explicit mapping in your DbContext for the object to table mapping.

Comment: No, you don't need to use `DbSet` to call stored procedures. There are a few ways you can accomplish this. See answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first

Comment: A DbSet is all the tables of a Database.  So if you are using one database you should only have one dataset.

Comment: @jdweng What you are talking about is `DbContext`. EF Core `DbSet<T>` is different thing - represents table, view or just queryable source inside the database.

Comment: The OP said " I need to create a DbSet for each of the tables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming EFCore given the tag and usage of FromSql.

For EFCore 2.1+ I would use a DbQuery (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbquery-1?view=efcore-2.2).

For EFCore 3.0, which has deprecated DbQuery, the replacement is a keyless DbSet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types).

I've done the former with stored procs and it works as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks!  I would still have to create an entity model to map the results of the stored procedure, correct?  Do I also need to create a migration for this too?

Comment: I got it to work.  Created a DbSet with an entity model that matched the results of the stored procedure.  Also changed FromSql to FromSqlRaw.

Comment: Yes, you will have to create a model.

Comment: In terms of a migration, that depends. Efcore can't automatically generate the code in this case so you'd have to create an empty migration and add the code to up/down the stored procedure yourself. I didn't do it this way as we migrated using another tool.

Comment: I working against a database that already contains the stored procedures I need to work with.  Trying to understand what is required.  Thx.

Comment: If the stored proc already exists outside of your code first migrations, then there is no need to create a migration for it.