# Problem when calling the Stored Procedure in Console application using EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, console-application

I tried to execute a stored procedure in my console application but what I get is a print of the sentence I want to call.

My stored procedure that I have created:

```
create proc Checked
@Links nvarchar(MAX)
as
SELECT CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM News
    WHERE LinkNews = @Links
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

And the method that I used to call the stored procedure inside the Console Application:

```
using (DbContextClass db = new DbContextClass())
{
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@Links", "http://www.newsline-ye.com/news7527.html");
    IEnumerable<New> n = db.Database.SqlQuery<New>("exec Checked @Links", p);
    Console.WriteLine(n);               
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

**My Problem** It gives me this output "exec Checked @Links" sentence

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: Not like that, I thank i did everything I should do @Dawood Awan

Comment: What is `New` type in your code?

Comment: This is class (the name of the table) @Voodoo

Answer (score 0):

```
List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
{
    new SqlParameter("Links", p);
}

string query = "EXECUTE Checked @Links";

var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<bool>(query, sqlParameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: Still no change

Comment: But you are returning `bool` only from SP