# Advanced database query

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, northwind

I have this method:

```
public async Task<ProductReport<ProductPrice>> GetCurrentProductsReport()
{
    var query = (DataServiceQuery<ProductPrice>)(
        from p in this.entities.Products
        where !p.Discontinued
        orderby p.ProductName
        select new ProductPrice
        {
            Name = p.ProductName,
            Price = p.UnitPrice ?? 0,
        });

    var result = await Task<IEnumerable<ProductPrice>>.Factory.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute(null, null), (ar) =>
    {
        return query.EndExecute(ar);
    });

    return new ProductReport<ProductPrice>(result);
}
```

This method returns an incomplete list of products. The number of items in the list is limited by the number of items that the service returns in one request.
I need to get all data.

I know I can use the `GetContinuation()` method, but I can't use it in this situation.

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do. Are you trying to load all of the data at one time or asynchronously iterate sets?

Comment: Add to a list in a loop?

Comment: I want to load the data at one time.

Comment: Why can't you use the [`GetContinuation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.services.client.queryoperationresponse.getcontinuation) method?

Comment: I can apply GetContinuation method, but I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get all data.

Create a stored procedure and extract the full total data rows/columns as needed.

Comment: Could you please explain in details?

Comment: If you can create a sproc or sprocs which will return the full set of data, why not call and extract the data that way? See [How to call a stored procedure with EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)