# ASP.Net Core - Entity Framework - Call Stored Procedure With No Return Data (in a void method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm current using ASP.Net Core with Entity Framework 3.1.1.  I want to just call a procedure as void instead of returning data.
Here my current setup for calling procedures and fitting the data into a model.

```
public List<MyModel> GetData(int ID)
{
    var result = (from x in _dbContext.MyModel.FromSqlRaw("ustp_ProcedureName {0}", param1)
                  select x).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

How do I do use FromSqlRaw, but in a void method and with a procedure that doesn't return data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get data better to use this:

```
 var result = _dbContext.MyModel
                  .FromSqlRaw("ustp_ProcedureName {0}", param1)
                  .ToList();
```

if you want to run sp that doesnt return  any data try this:

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ustp_ProcedureName {0}", param1);
```

Comment: That did it.   Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a stored procedure in your DbContext class as follows.

this.Database.SqlQuery("storedProcedureName",params);

ref : [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)