# how to call stored procedure with parameter in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am getting below error when I am calling procedure from entity framework with parameter

alter proc GetResultsForCampaign
@aa int
as
begin
SELECT aa from xyz
end

calling code
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery("GetResultsForCampaign @aa", 22).ToList();

error must declare the variable @aa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

var result = await db.Context
  .FromSqlRaw("exec [dbo].[your_sp] @param1, @param2", 
    new SqlParameter("param1", value1),     
    new SqlParameter("param2", value2))
  .AsNoTracking() // optional
  .ToListAsync()
```