# I want call stored procedure to insert some value to database using netcore entity framework 5 , the stored procedure work perfectly in pgadmin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

these the values that i want to pass i try a lot but nothing work

```
 [HttpPost]
                public async Task< IActionResult> Adduser(string fname , string lname , string pass , string uname , string actname , int cnumber , string cname , string depname  )
                {
        
                     var result =await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"call transfer @fname,@lname, @pass,@uname,@actname,@cnumber,@cname,@depname {fname},{lname},{pass},{uname},{actname},{cnumber},{cname},{depname} " );
                      await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
                    return Ok();
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first on how to call stored procedures in Entity Framework.

Comment: Does it  report any error or just return 0? Have you tried to use `ExecuteSqlInterpolated()` instead of use `ExecuteSqlRawAsync()`?

Comment: the error show it to me is the first argument i give like when i give the fname(mark) the error is syntax error near or at mark

Comment: also i use ExecuteSqlInterpolated() doesnot work either i am getting tired of this really :(

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$"exec transfer @fname ='{fname.Replace("'", "''")}',@lname ='{lname.Replace("'", "''")}', @pass ='{pass.Replace("'", "''")}',@uname ='{uname.Replace("'", "''")}',@actname ='{actname.Replace("'", "''")}',@cnumber ={cnumber},@cname ='{cname.Replace("'", "''")}',@depname ='{depname.Replace("'", "''")}'"
```

The "replace" calls are intended to prevent SQL Injection.  I assumed everything was a string on the SQL side, but quoting shouldn't hurt in most cases if they aren't.

Comment: it show me error in int value cnumber

Comment: @MuntherAlkhwaldeh I missed that it was an Int. I removed the Replace (as it can't be the source of SQL injection... and doesn't have that function) and the SQL quotes around it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort , but still does not working  , its show me error near or at @ i delete it also show me error near or at fname also delete it error the name i give it for first argument(syntax error at or near "Mark") :(

Comment: @MuntherAlkhwaldeh Give it one last try.  I updated the statement