# dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw can't return a string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to return a string from a SQL Server stored procedure in a Blazor app using Entity Framework.

This is follow on from [another GitHub post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

The in-ap code is

```
string outList = "";

var xparams = new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter("@Start", 10),
    new SqlParameter("@End", 20),
    new SqlParameter("@output", outList) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }
};

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec GetMe  @Start, @End, @output output", xparams);
var ReturnValue = ((SqlParameter)xparams[2]).Value;
```

The problem is that the return value is only the first character. The stored procedure parameters are:

```sql
@Start int,
@End int,
@output varchar(50) output
```

And the assignment is:

```sql
Select @output = 'This is some text';
Return
```

- If I use `Set` instead of `Select`, the result is the same
- If I use a scalar type like int, float, real, date, the return value is correct
- If I initialise the string to be non blank the result is still the same
- The stored procedure runs OK in SSMS

I guess it something to do with multi-dimension data.

Comment: can you instead of `new SqlParameter("@output",outList)` do `new SqlParameter("@output",SqlDbType.VarChar)`  and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Always declare the parameter size. In particular with strings

Comment: And to clarify, just so there's no confusion, the parameter size needs to match the stored procedure signature definition - not the length of any string(s) that you may currently have in the client-side code.

Comment: Thanks to all for clarifying this. Issue is now resolved. Now for returning collections from a SP in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve problem by changing the output `SqlParameter` by adding the datatype such as `SqlDbType.NVarChar` or `SqlDbType.VarChar`.

This is the correct code

```
var xparams = new SqlParameter[] {
                  new SqlParameter("@Start", 10),
                  new SqlParameter("@End", 20),
                  new SqlParameter("@output", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }
              };

SchoolContext _context = new SchoolContext();

_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec GetMe  @Start, @End, @output output", xparams);
var ReturnValue = ((SqlParameter)xparams[2]).Value;
```

`SqlParameter` has 7 constructors, you use constructor #1, but you should instead use constructor #2 or #3:

1. `SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value)`
2. `SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size)`
3. `SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType)`
4. `SqlParameter()`
5. `SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size, ParameterDirection direction, bool isNullable, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn, DataRowVersion sourceVersion, object value)`
6. `SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size, ParameterDirection direction, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn, DataRowVersion sourceVersion, bool sourceColumnNullMapping, object value, string xmlSchemaCollectionDatabase, string xmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema, string xmlSchemaCollectionName)`
7. `SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size, string sourceColumn)`