# Calling a stored procedure form EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following, it produces an error saying I need to specify the parameter SearchCriteria which is the only parameter of the stored procedure, am I missing something here?

```
public async Task<List<T>> SqlQueryAsync<T>(string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
     {

         return await _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters).ToListAsync();

     }
```

The calling code has this

```
object[] args = new object[] { searchQuery };
var list = await _repository.SqlQueryAsync<Landlord>(StoredProcedures.LandlordSearch, args);

public static readonly string LandlordSearch = "LandlordSearch @SearchCriteria";
```

Comment: No, I did not think I needed to - I will do that and try it again

Comment: The problem there is that it becomes very specific and not generic

Comment: Found this post, which solved the issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792018/how-to-access-context-database-sqlquery-in-entity-framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792018/how-to-access-context-database-sqlquery-in-entity-framework